# How to create dynamic control event handler

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, event-handling

I have problem with control event handler. I created a control ( button ) and I want to bind click event with a method. But I have "Error binding to target method." exception.

code is,

```
class SetControlEvent
{

    public void Sleep()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    internal void Set(object theObject,XmlNode theControlNode)
    {
        EventInfo ei = theObject.GetType().GetEvent("Click");


        EventDescriptorCollection events = TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(theObject);
        foreach (EventDescriptor theEvent in events)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in theControlNode.Attributes)
            {
                if (theEvent.DisplayName == attribute.Name)
                {

                    MethodInfo mi = typeof(SetControlEvent).GetMethod("Sleep");
                    Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, this, "Sleep");

                    theEvent.AddEventHandler(theObject, del);



                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

so, what should I do?

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Sleep` method signature isn't adequate to [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate.

Try this:

```
    public void Sleep(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```